# Block text isolation from log files

Tags: shell, unix, sed, pattern-matching

I tend to look at my log files for errors during a server startup and `less` is used to achieve this.

However, I want something more efficient.

I want to see logs between two patterns "server stopping" and "startup"
I've achieved this using `sed`

```
sed -n '/Stopping/,/Server startup/p' test.txt
```

This works fine but there's a problem. the log file contains this patterns over and over again (as the server stops and starts), how can I get only the last block of this pattern? (which will be the last shutdown of the server and logs while is starting).

Comment: try `tac test.txt | sed -n '/Server startup/,/Stopping/{p;/Stopping/q}' | tac`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution based on `tac` and `sed`:

```
tac test.txt  | sed -e '/stopping/,$d' |  tac | sed -e '/startup/,$d'
```

**Explained:**

`tac` concatenate and print files in reverse.

`sed -e '/your_keyword/,$d'` outputs lines from begining until 'your_keyword' is reached.

...so print your log file starting from the end, cut first part, reverse again, cut second part ...et voilà!

To test it:

```
echo  "
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxx start xxxx
aaa1
aaa2
xx stop xxx
xxxyyyyxxxxyyyxxxx
xxxyyyyxxxxyyyxxxx
xyyyxx start xxxyyyyx
bbb1
bbb2
yy stop yy
yyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyy" | tac |sed -e '/start/,$d' |  tac | sed -e '/stop/,$d'
```

Output:

```
bbb1
bbb2
```

Comment: what if I want to include start and stop into the echo?

Comment: I imagine you will use the command line to filter the file 'test.txt' (as named in your question) to isolate log blocks. I.e. _tac test.txt | sed -e ..._
...so it's not clear to me what 'echo' are you talking about. Please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry what I simply meant is that you're solution shows bbb1 and bbb2, which is what is between the two texts string I provided. What I am asking is if I can include "start" and "stop" string lines in the desired output so the output is "start" bbb1 bbb2 "stop"

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed '/Stopping/,/Server startup/{/Stopping/h;//!H};$!d;x' file
```

Store each occurence of the required lines in the hold space (HS) and delete all other lines. At end-of-file swap to the HS and print what has been stored.

The latest lines in the HS will have over-written any previous such lines.

Answer (score 0):

Never use range expressions as they make the code for trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then slightly more interesting tasks require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions. Just use awk so you can simply use a flag instead of having to try to force ranges to work and you can even do string comparisons rather than regexp comparisons if appropriate.

To print from the last line containing `5` through the last line containing `8`:

```
$ seq 20 | awk '/5/{f=1;s=""} f{s=s $0 ORS} /8/{f=0} END{printf "%s", s}'
15
16
17
18
```